# Install PyTorch - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch

Tags: python, pytorch

When I install PyTorch using

```
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

(because I don't have GPU), I get:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

My Python and `pip` version is **3.12**.

I've used all the methods mentioned on StackOverflow, but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Downgrade python to 3.11

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PyTorch on Windows only supports Python 3.8-3.11; Python 2.x is not supported. [Source](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-python)

You need to downgrade your python to `3.11` as [@Dr.Snoopy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/dr-snoopy) commented.